# What happen to the children of a process that call setsid()?

Tags: c, unix, signals, posix

Working on the POSIX signal emulation for [Jehanne](http://jehanne.io), I realized that the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsid.html) does not explain what happens to the existing children of a process that calls `setsid()`.

I wonder if they remain in the previous session and process group or they will follow the parent in the new session.

And, if they remain in the previous session/group, will the parent still receive SIGCHLD when they exit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing; they retain their session. And SIGCHLD has nothing to do with sessions, just parent-child relationship.